# php code not working xampp

Tags: php, regex

I am doing something with regex but the code below doesn't work on my computer somehow. I am using XAMPP package. However when i checked my php code on this website https://ideone.com/nFkBnC it was working. Why this is happening ?

```
<?php
$single="<div id='quote'>

</br><input onclick='this.select();' id='selectable' value='User
'></br><div class='content'>
^^^^^ MILAN TODAY ^^^^^



4
-4-
4444
44444
444444
4444444
44444444
444444444
*3333333333*
444444444
44444444
4444444
444444
44444
4444
444
44
4
*
# 670 # ((( 30 ))) # 370 #

# 789 # ((( 40 ))) # 370 #

***gl***
</br></div></div>";

if (preg_match('/(\R4{3,4}\D44\D)/', $single, $double)) {
        echo "working";
}

?>
```

The same code echo "working" on this site but its false on my pc.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm guessing the code is taking overly long coffee breaks, just leaning on its shovel, chatting with the rake, etc... Sounds like a bad employee, shoud be fired.

Comment: Is should echo working if it is working but it does not do so.

Comment: `preg_match` does not return 'true' or 'false', *"it returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred."* So you likely want `if (preg_match('/(\R4{3,4}\D44\D)/', $single) == 1)` `$double` would contain the matches.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thats ok. But why the results are diffrent on the website and on my local computer. It echo nothing on my pc.

Comment: Probably because you're running something different than your website is running. PHP may be a different version or configured differently.

Comment: OK. Seems correct.

Comment: Are you running script from PHP CLI?

Comment: No. I am running direct in browser.

Comment: Would you please do a `echo strlen($single);` in both local environment and the host it works?

Comment: Did it. Both are diffrent. One returns 347 and another returns 379. The one i tested in localhost return 379 and the one i tested online return 347. Looks like you got it. Can you tell me what to do next ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows a newline denotes two characters: a carriage return following a line-feed: `CR`+`LF`. In working with a pattern based utility this two characters have almost one way of representation `\r\n`. But Unix-like systems represent a newline with one character: `LF`

While running your script on a host on top of Linux, your RegEx `\R4{3,4}\D44\D` works because `\D` is able to match a line-feed `\n` (`\x0A`) and immediately `44` matches.

```
                                             Here
                                           _________
                                          |         |
  4    4    4    4    .    4    4    4    .    4    4
  ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
\x04 \x04 \x04 \x04 \x0A \x04 \x04 \x04 \x0A \x04 \x04
```

But in Windows things differ a little. `\D` matches a `CR` (`\x0D`) but following `LF` (`\x0A`) is never matched because your engine immediately looks for `44`. So whole pattern fails.

```
                                                     Here
                                                ______________
                                               |              |
  4    4    4    4    .    .    4    4    4    .    .    4    4
  ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
\x04 \x04 \x04 \x04 \x0D \x0A \x04 \x04 \x04 \x0D \x0A \x04 \x04
```

Saying that, I believe **347** is output of `strlen()` on Linux host and **379** came from your Windows host. A basic math results a number which is the same number of new lines in your input string:

```
379 - 347 =  32 // CR characters in Windows OS
```

But if you change your RegEx to `\R4{3,4}\D{1,2}44\D` you will see it works or if you only mean newlines you should really change it to:

```
\R4{3,4}\R44\R
```

`\R` matches any kind of newlines (i.e. `CR`+`LF`, `LF`, `CR`, ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me and i understood more about regex. :)